# Conditional statement in react doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

I am trying to show a specific form for review if the user is:

```
1. Is logged in
2. Is not administrator
3. Is not a moderator
```

So my code goes like this:

```
<h2>Write a Review</h2>
           {errorResortReview && <Message variant='danger'>{errorResortReview}</Message>}
            {userInfo && (userInfo.role !== 'administrator' || userInfo.role !== 'resortOwner') ? (
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label for="rating">Rating</label>

                <ReactStars
                    count={5}
                    onChange={setRatingInput}
                    size={34}
                    activeColor="#ffd700"
                />
 
             </div>
  
            <div class="form-group">
               <textarea className="form-control" value={comment} onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)} id="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
            
            ) : <Message>Please <Link to='/login'>Login</Link> to write a review</Message>}
        </li>
```

When I tried this on my react component, it's still showing the form even if the user is administrator and moderator.

Note: userInfo holds the data of the currently login user.

Can anyone spot the problem here?

Comment: This will always be true, right? `userInfo.role !== 'administrator' || userInfo.role !== 'resortOwner'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be, `userInfo && userInfo.role !== 'administrator' && userInfo.role !== 'resortOwner'` ?

Answer (score 5):

Your logic here is incorrect:

```
{userInfo && (userInfo.role !== 'administrator' || userInfo.role !== 'resortOwner') ? (
```

To implement the logic of:

```
1. Is logged in
2. Is not administrator
3. Is not a moderator
```

Use:

```
{(userInfo && userInfo.role !== 'administrator' && userInfo.role !== 'resortOwner') ? (
```